# 404 page when i click on custom configuration tab in magento

Tags: magento

I have created a custom configuration tab in back end under system configuration. I am getting 404 page when i click on my tab link.

My system.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <tabs>
    <instagram translate="label" module="instagram">
        <label>Instagram Extensions</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </instagram>
</tabs>
<sections>
     <instagram translate="label" module="instagram">
        <label>Instagram Options</label>
        <tab>instagram</tab>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
         <groups>
            <instagram_group translate="label" module="instagram">
                <label>My Extension Options</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            </instagram_group>
        </groups>
    </instagram>
</sections>
</config>
```

Can anyone tell me the mistake i have done??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: logout and then  login again in admin panel.

Comment: I did, Still i get 404 error.

Comment: have you checked ACL for that module?

Comment: No.. What is that? I am new to magento.. I cant get you.

Comment: read this http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration

Comment: You are right.. I have to give ACL in config.xml file.. Thank you so much. I got it now.

Comment: Oh. thanks you so much @dushyant

Comment: was that the only issue right?

Comment: Yes, I did not give ACL in config.xml file. It worked fine once i included acl in config.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look on these blogs.
[create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension](http://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/) 
[custom_magento_system_configuration](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration)

According to your code you might miss the ACL implementation.